# Por que as chamadas de atributos não definidos na classe é possível?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes, atributos

Não sei se isso é um comportamento padrão em POO, mas pelo que tenho estudado, quando coloco o `objeto.metodo_ou_atributo` deveria chamar algum método ou atributo que foi definido na classe previamente, mas no trecho do código abaixo há a classe `Pessoa` e dentro dessa classe só está definido o atributo `nome`. Ao instanciar essa classe `p1 = Pessoa("João")` o nome "João" vai para o atributo `self.nome`. Até ai tudo bem.

Mas por que `p1.outra_coisa = "Carlos"` é aceito, se `outra_coisa` não está definido como atributo da classe `Pessoa`? Estou criando algum atributo temporário no objeto ou algo do tipo? Isso é alguma má pratica que deve ser evitada?

```
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self, nome: str):
        self.nome = nome


p1 = Pessoa("João")
p1.outra_coisa = "Carlos"

print(p1.outra_coisa)
print(p1.nome)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quase nada é um comportamento de POO. Orientação a objeto é algo secundário da programação e não tem o valor que algumas pessoas acham que tem. OO é aprendido errado pela maioria das pessoas, se é que pode-se chamar de aprender.

O comportamento mostrado é definido pela qualidade da tipagem de Python que é definida como dinâmica. [Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101), e [também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101).

Em tipagem dinâmica os objetos não tem uma forma muito definida, eles são o que são. Então a classe de Python é só uma dica do que você espera que o objeto tenha e realize, mas nada impede do objeto criado com base nela seja modificado e fique diferente do que a classe projetou. Fica a cargo do programador não abusar disto.

É um mecanismo que dá alguma vantagem, mas perde-se a [robustez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/463132/101). Por isso Python não é uma linguagem adequada para grandes projetos, apenas para *scripts*, mesmo que muitas pessoas usem:

[image: Carro transportando um cavalo no banco de trás]

O ideal é evitar esse tipo de coisa sim.

Classes em Python na verdade são dicionários um pouco modificados, então é só colocar uma chave nova e é aceito. [Dá até para apagar certas partes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#delattr) e jogar fora todo contrato, afinal Python, por definição, não respeita contratos (tem outras formas mas não vem ao caso). Então se você disse que quer colocar algo na classe, é aceito.

É assim com todas linguagens de tipagem dinâmica. Se quer contratos fortes precisa procurar linguagens com tipagem estática e forte com bom nível de *soundness*. Se precisa de liberdade para fazer o que bem entender no código (não confundir com o resultado final) então Python é uma boa escolha.