# Quais os principais defeitos do sistema de tipos do Java?

Tags: java, tipagem

Não entendo de sistemas de tipos. Mas ouço falar que o sistema de tipos do Java é falho (exemplos [aqui](https://wouter.coekaerts.be/2018/java-type-system-broken) e [aqui](https://hackernoon.com/java-is-unsound-28c84cb2b3f)). Então gostaria de saber mais detalhes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É difícil fazer uma lista completa, precisaria de um estudo completo, e se alguém fizer é só olhar para ele. Os *links* são bons começos.

Todo sistema de tipo tem defeitos, ou pelo menos desvantagens, algumas decisões do que usar são *tradeoffs*, então se optar por não ter um defeito terá outro.

Sistemas que tendem mais próximos da perfeição matemática costumam ter uma UX bem ruim e exigem que o programador cuide de tantos detalhes que se torna pouco prático usar a linguagem tão maravilhosa. Isso ocorre um pouco com Haskell. Diz-se, hiperbolicamente, que se você compilar um código em Haskell ele será correto.

Obviamente que nenhum sistema de tipos resolve a coleta de requisitos feita errado ou a implementação errada, ou seja, a linguagem (Haskell) não deixa você fazer errado algo certo, mas você pode fazer o errado sem problemas :)

Java é uma linguagem que busca robustez, mas nem tanto. Isso é uma qualidade, mas é um defeito no sentido que exige muita anotação (eventualmente inferido, mas ainda pode exigir mais que outras linguagens menos robustas). É um dos motivos dela ser considerada verbosa, embora isso esteja melhorando, e ela é verbosa por outras razões, tem linguagem mais robustas com menos *boilerplate*.

Seria bom começar por:

- [O que é um tipo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/532890/101)
- [O que é estilo de tipagem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101)
- [Qual o significado da palavra Soundness no contexto de linguagens de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/463132/101)

E claro, seguir os *links*.

Como contexto básico temos que entender que Java foi mal nascida, e apesar de ter melhorado em vários pontos, muito erro não pode mais ser corrigido, isso é comum no sistema de tipos que tem poucos mecanismos tão [ortogonais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195461/101).

## Defeitos

Alguns defeitos se referem à filosofia de facilidade da linguagem, então o sistema de tipos não deixa fazer certas operações para ser mais fácil para o programador, para evitar que ele cometa erros, o que ele não pode fazer não está errado.

Então evita-se certos tipos que poderiam ser inseguros, ou pode criar algum [efeito colateral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/101) (quando que tenha muito efeito colateral em Java, por isso um dos defeitos talvez seja a inconsistência). Não tem ponteiro, não pode passar objetos por referência, ao menos explicitamente. Isso cria limitações, mas claro que não impede o uso geral. Em alguns casos isso é feito para não errar ou ter que anotar o [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) dos objetos, que é algo complicado.

Talvez o maior defeito, que não é um pecado mortal, muitas linguagens são assim, mas é mais grave quando a linguagem sempre se vendeu com uma característica que ela não tem, por exemplo **nem tudo deriva de `Object`** nela, que traz vários problemas, cria exceções de como trabalhar. Isto é perfeitamente possível.

Não sei se vale falar de problemas mais específicos, como ter muita coisa em `Object` que não serve para tudo, então há um enorme desperdício. Isso não é bem do sistema de tipos, mas afeta todos os tipos.

Outro problema bem complicado é o tal do [***generics***](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101) que foi introduzido depois da linguagem estar na rua e para não quebrar compatibilidade ficou bem debilitada, sendo ineficiente em certos aspectos, não tão seguro, pouco flexível e até falso sob certo ponto de vista. Sem boa genericidade não tem como obter robustez total. Linguagens de tipagem estática sem esse mecanismo ficam mancas.

E aí entramos no problema da **nulidade** que quebra a robustez e de certa forma a linguagem deixa de ser tão estática assim. Um objeto de um tipo poder ter o valor de um outro tipo (`null`) é um enorme erro em qualquer linguagem que considere que é bom poder ter apenas um só tipo em algo nominado. O nulo não é problema em linguagens de baixa robustez, porque aí a baixa robustez é o defeito (e qualidade).

É claro que nem toda exceção no sistema de tipos é defeito, mas fica complicado se você começar admitir exceções só para dizer que não tem defeitos. Se considerar que tudo documentado não é defeito então Java talvez não tenha defeitos. JavaScript também não.

E aí acho que é hora de falar do **mecanismo de exceção** (`throw`/`catch`) que acaba afetando o sistema de tipos impedindo certas soluções nele, deixando o programador ter que lidar com algo que o sistema de tipos não resolveu. Ele é um defeito porque ele permite contornar o sistema de tipos, mas novamente, também é uma solução para diminuir a complexidade. A exceção não faz parte do sistema de tipos, mas o afeta bastante, assim como acontece com o nulo.

Outro defeito é fazer *casting* em alguns casos que não dá o resultado esperado. Java faz muitas coisas virarem `string` implicitamente, e o resultado pode ser indesejado. Existem outros ***castings* automáticos**, que não deixam de ser defeitos, há quem considere sempre ruim, mas nem sempre causa problema real. É mais estranho, e de certa forma outro defeito correlato, que em certos casos acontece a promoção e outros não, não é linear.

Em alguns tipos **falta [variância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32880/101)**, assim algumas coisas problemáticas são aceitas e outras factíveis são rejeitadas. O *array* não tem variância. Nem todos os tipos de biblioteca foram criados com variância em mente, até porque o mecanismo de anotação dele não existia no começo e nem sempre dá para fazer corretamente.

[Veja sobre o operador condicional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839244/ternary-operator-with-different-types-of-expressions). Qualifica como defeito do sistema de tipos?

O simples uso de `Object` é um defeito que o sistema de tipos permite?

O fato de um método ter um determinado contrato exigido, mas nominalmente nada indica isto, é um defeito que não compile?

Vale falar por exemplo, que os tipos chamados [primitivos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/101), ou mesmo suas contrapartes em classes não possuem boas especificações de capacidade?

Você não pode criar um método que receba um tipo numérico qualquer com capacidade de fazer uma adição, não importa qual seja o tipo desde que ele tenha essa capacidade. O programador tem que se virar, o sistema de tipos não ajuda.

É defeito não ter contratos onde você pode ir além do que o sistema de tipos propõe?

É defeito não ter certas características como um ADT, *type classes*, uniões, ou o `enum` não ser bem um enumeração simples (ou é qualidade)?

Ser mutável por padrão é um defeito do sistema de tipos? Ou qualidade?

Incentivar impureza e não ter como forçar a pureza parece defeito.

Algumas pessoas dirão que o fato das classes não serem [cidadãs de primeira classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227485/101) é um defeito.

Logo não terá a seguinte deficiência, mas certamente terá problema para implementar sem quebrar compatibilidade, por isso há anos vem sendo adiado o tipo por valor personalizado pelo usuário (programador). Como será? Derivará de `Object`? Poderá criar "[primitivos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/101)"? Como isso trabalhará com o que já existe, especialmente *generics*? Terá um buraco enorme, mas consertar o defeito e não poder expressar um tipo tão óbvio que toda aplicação real possui. Eu acho que **não poder criar `struct`** um dos maiores defeitos de Java.

E quando tiver isso, virá tudo o que abre possibilidade, ou colocará uma perna que faltava mas será extremamente manco?

Achei uma [resposta interessante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12941805/221800) sobre um ponto que nunca refleti muito.

Nem tudo que eu falei é sobre o sistema de tipos de verdade, tem relação com ele apenas.

Toda linguagem tem problemas com o sistema de tipos quando vai conversar com outras linguagens, é simples, eles são incompatíveis, até mesmo entre C e C++ acontece.

Nem falei de tipos específicos terem problemas, porque aí acho que não é o sistema de tipos.

Tem muito problema que nem vale a pena consertar, quase todo código existente não se beneficiará e dificultará os novos aproveitar.

Sistema de tipos tem que nascer certo. Pode até faltar um ou outro ponto, pode ser mais restritivo do que deveria ser desde que tirar a restrição depois não crie problemas.

## Artigos *linkados*

Em um deles fala sobre *corner case*. Eles existem virtualmente em todas linguagens, eles são defeitos, não há dúvidas disto, mas consertar pode gerar um defeito pior na linguagem. E quando falo de consertar nem considero a quebra de compatibilidade, falo puramente mesmo. Quebra de compatibilidade ajuda consertar defeitos, mesmo gerando outro defeito pragmático na linguagem, mas o sistema de tipos agradece.

Não vou ficar repetindo tudo o que já foi falando, lá tem *insights* interessantes sobre o uso de *wildcard*, ou como as *lambdas* foram mal implementadas.

*Inner classes* existem porque no começo não queriam ter *lambdas*, queriam ser *puramente orientada a objeto, sem nunca ter sido, ou seja, o marketing, as luzes e fumaças eram mais importantes, então criaram algo ruim, com defeitos já citados lá para evitar que a linguagem parecesse funcional. Não preciso dizer como estavam errados.

## Conclusão

Em resumo, qualquer coisa que quebre garantias, é potencialmente um defeito do sistema de tipos, mesmo que documentado. Você morrer em um carro é um defeito dele, ainda que documentado. Nem todo defeito compensa consertar, também é qualidade do carro "custar barato", ser fácil de dirigir, ou ser de tamanho razoável, etc.

Difícil falar em principais, não é tão fácil classificar quais são eles e quais são secundários, ainda mais no meu caso, que não sou um estudioso profundo sobre sistema de tipos, certamente esta não é a melhor resposta que pode obter.

Pode ser que eu lembre de outros quando cruzarem meu caminho, quem sabe eu lembre de atualizar aqui.

Para uma avaliação completa e pessoal precisa estudar muito os meandros da computação, ver o que outras linguagens fazem.

Faça mais perguntas específicas (pesquise antes). Responderei o que me motivar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).